# How to delete duplicates with condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
CompanyNumber   Name  Status     other column1    other Column2
     10           A     Active
     10           A      NULL
     11           B     Active
     11           B       NULL
     12           C     Active
     12           C        NULL
     13           D        NULL
     14           E      Active


     ...
```

So over 300 000 rows like this.

I would like to delete the one that has status NULL and the resulting table should be like below :

```
      CompanyNumber    Name    Status
         10              A       Active
         11              B       Active
         12              C       Active
         13              D       NULL
         14              E       Active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( 
 SELECT CompanyNumber
      ,Name 
      ,[Status]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyNumber, Name ORDER BY [Status] DESC) rn 
 FROM @TABLE
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: It was hard to understand it but this was the only one gave me the correct result. thanks

Comment: Not hard at all, just google what windowing functions are and how they work with "PARTITION BY" clause. good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

I get that you want to delete row where status is null. Try SQL with where clause like

```
DELETE
FROM mytable
WHERE status is null
```

If you wish to remove only duplicate rows then you could do something like:

```
DELETE
FROM mytable
WHERE status is null
AND CompanyNumber  IN (SELECT CompanyNumber 
                       FROM mytable
                       GROUP BY CompanyNumber 
                       HAVING COUNT(CompanyNumber) > 1)
```

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention that there are other rows that has active and is not duplicated.

Comment: OK i think second query would work for you. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

if you want retain first record and delete other duplicate record then  Check this...

```
   select *,
row_number() over  (partition by CompanyNumber   order by CompanyNumber)as rno 
into  #temp  from table 

  delete * from 
  table 
 where CompanyNumber in
 (select CompanyNumber  from #temp where rno != 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exists clause in your where statement to find null lines with duplicates:

```
delete
from   tableA
where  tableA.Status is null
and    exists (
           select *
           from   tableA t2
           where  t2.CompanyNumber = tableA.CompanyNumber 
           and    t2.Name = tableA.Name and not t2.Status is null
       )
```

Comment: Cannot see t1 in your query?